# Django template add and compare does not work on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-templates

This basic piece of templating code works perfectly fine on localhost.

succes_view.html:

```
<div id="center">
  Block {{block_number}} succesfully submitted to database. 
  {% if block_number < 5 %}
    <a href='/block/{{block_number|add:"1" }}'> Click here to proceed </a>
 {% else %}
    <p>You completed the task. Thank you and goodbye!
 {% endif %}
</div>
```

When staging on Heroku the " < " and the "|add:" functionality do not work as expected. It seems the integer is interpreted as a string (eg 2 |add:"1" would return 21 instead of 3).

Any ideas on what's going wrong here and how to solve it?

All help appreciated!

Joris

EDIT: The functionality is now broken on localhost as well. So it's not a Heroku issue anymore. For completeness the relevant parts of view.py and urls.py

views.py:

```
def succes_view(request, block_number):
    return render(request, 'block/succes_view.html', {'block_number': block_number})
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^succes_view/(?P<block_number>[1-5])/$', views.succes_view, name='succes_view'), 
]
```

Comment: Of course I can hack my way around it, but I would like to understand why Heroku breaks this functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters from the URL are always strings. Since you know it is always going to be a digit between 1 and 5, you can convert it to an int in the view:

```
return render(request, 'block/succes_view.html', {'block_number': int(block_number)})
```

Comment: That 's a clear and elegant solution. Thanks a lot!

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#built-in-filter-reference):

This filter will first try to coerce both values to integers. If this fails, it’ll attempt to add the values together anyway. This will work on some data types (strings, list, etc.) and fail on others. If it fails, the result will be an empty string.

So that is why template math will work 'sometimes' on strings..